# Why does Kotlin have Mutable versions of collections?

Tags: kotlin, language-design, mutablelist

I have a general question about Kotlin collections.

Why are there mutable versions of so many collections (like the `MutableList`) when we have the `val` vs `var` distinction?

Well....ok...actually, I understand that `val` doesn't have anything to do with the 'mutability' of the object, but rather the 're-initializability' of the object.

But then that raises the question....why isn't `MutableList` the default?

Comment: Have you read through the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html#collection-types)? One of the reasons is immutable lists are **covariant** while mutable ones are not.

Comment: Mutable collections allow you modify what is inside them. A `var` lets you assign a different collection to the variable. Mutability can be used to help optimize code, because it can avoid repeatedly copying the entire contents of a list when you are only changing some of the contents. Or you might need it for some recursive operations. Just a couple of examples.

Comment: @Pawel Why not make a unified interface which is covariant, but has type-checks enforced in all of the modifying methods like `add()` and `remove()`? So, you'd get `null` if you tried an illegal modification.

Comment: Generics provide compile time safety and (at least on JVM) both mutable/immutable variants are backed by native collection implementations. Having runtime check (which would introduce quite a bit of overhead) is against the design and just asking for issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Individually, mutable and immutable collections are able to expose useful features that can't co-exist in a single interface:

1. Mutable collections can be read from *and* written to. But Kotlin strives to avoid all runtime failures, therefore, these mutable collections are invariant.
2. Immutable collections are covariant, but they're...well...immutable. Still, Kotlin does provide mechanisms for doing useful things with these immutable collections (like filtering values or creating new immutable collections from existing ones). You can go through [the long list of convenience functions for Kotlin's (immutable) `List` interface](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/) for examples.

---

Immutable collections in Kotlin cannot have elements added or removed from them; they can only be read from. But this apparent restriction makes it possible to do some subtyping with the immutable collections. From the Kotlin docs:

> The read-only collection types are covariant...the collection types have the same subtyping relationship as the element types.

This means that, if a `Rectangle` class is a child of a `Shape` class, you can place a `List<Rectangle>` object in a `List<Shape>` variable whenever required:

```kotlin
fun stackShapes(val shapesList: List<Shape>) {
    ...
}

val rectangleList = listOf<Rectangle>(...)

// This is valid!
stackShapes(rectangleList)
```

Mutable collections, on the other hand, can be read from *and* written to. Because of this, no sub-typing or super-typing is possible with them. From the Kotlin docs:

> ...mutable collections aren't covariant; otherwise, this would lead to runtime failures. If `MutableList<Rectangle>` was a subtype of `MutableList<Shape>`, you could insert other Shape inheritors (for example, Circle) into it, thus violating its Rectangle type argument.

```kotlin
val rectangleList = mutableListOf<Rectangle>(...);
val shapesList: MutableList<Shape> = rectangleList // MutableList<Rectangle>-type object in MutableList<Shape>-type variable

val circle = Circle(...)
val shape: Shape = circle // Circle-type object in Shape-type variable

// Runtime Error!
shapesList.add(shape) // You're actually trying to add a Circle to a MutableList<Rectangle>
// If rectanglesList couldn't be put into a variable with type MutableList<Shape> in the first place, you would never have run into this problem.
```

At this point, you might be thinking: "So what? Kotlin could just add type-checks to all of the write-methods of Mutable Collections...then you could allow them to be covariant, *and* you wouldn't need separate immutable collections!"

Which is true, except that it would go completely against a core Kotlin philosophy; to avoid `nulls` and runtime errors whenever possible. You see, the methods of such a Collection would have to return `null` - or raise an Exception - whenever a type-check fails. This would only become apparent at runtime, and since that can be avoided by simply making Mutable Collections invariant...that's exactly what Kotlin does.

Answer (score 0):

From the Kotlin docs:

> The read-only collection types are covariant. This means that, if a Rectangle class inherits from Shape, you can use a `List<Rectangle>` anywhere the `List<Shape>` is required. In other words, the collection types have the same subtyping relationship as the element types. Maps are covariant on the value type, but not on the key type.

> In turn, mutable collections aren't covariant; otherwise, this would lead to runtime failures. If `MutableList<Rectangle>` was a subtype of `MutableList<Shape>`, you could insert other Shape inheritors (for example, Circle) into it, thus violating its Rectangle type argument.

To paraphrase, if it's immutable you know all the types are the same. If not, you might have different inheritors.

Comment: Why not make a unified interface which is covariant, but has type-checks enforced in all of the modifying methods like `add()` and `remove()`? So, you'd get `null` if you tried an illegal modification.

Comment: I didn't write the spec, but my guess is it's a matter of tradeoffs? You'd be adding type checks every time you add or remove.